# MongoDB How do I return documents with calculated fields based on other documents in the collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm basically looking for where to start with best practices on a query that's confounding me.

I have a collection of mobile devices. Simplified it looks something like this:

```
[
    { number: 2145551234, reportDate: 201704, zeroUse: true },
    { number: 2145551234, reportDate: 201703, zeroUse: false },
    { number: 2145551212, reportDate: 201704, zeroUse: false },
    { number: 2145551212, reportDate: 201703, zeroUse: false },
    { number: 2145558888, reportDate: 201704, zeroUse: false },
    ...
]
```

I am trying to write a query which does the following:

1. pulls all documents for 201704
2. returns an additional field `lastDateUsed` for each document such that if, in the case of the first document, the zeroUse flag is true, it looks for the next latest date where the zeroUse flag was false for that number, in this case, 201703

At the core of the issue is my desire to not have to run such a query against each 1000+ documents to determine the result.

My plan was to perform this calculation once on insert so it doesn't need to be recalculated every time there is a query.

Further, I am equally happy with either no property if the zeroUse value is false, or a `lastDateUsed` property with the current date.

Comment: What queries have you attempted? What results were you getting?